# MySQL select last image in LEFT JOIN

Tags: php, mysql, sql, joomla

I have this function that lists the first inserted image and other data from accommodation database.

```
function getLIST($sort_by,$saved=0,$filter)
{
    $session = JFactory::getSession();
    $lang =& JFactory::getLanguage();

    $query = "SELECT a.id FROM #__jomholiday_fields AS a where a.name='COM_JOMHOLIDAY_ACCOMODATION_RATING'";
    $db = $this->getDbo();
    $db->setQuery( $query );
    $rating_id = $db->loadResult();

    $query = "SELECT a.id FROM #__jomholiday_fields AS a where a.name='COM_JOMHOLIDAY_BOARD_BASIS'";
    $db->setQuery( $query );
    $board_basis_id = $db->loadResult();

    $query  = $db->getQuery(true);

    $listing_expiry_days=(int)$this->getConf("listing_expiry_days");
    if($listing_expiry_days)
    {
        $now=strtotime("now");
        $temp=$now-$listing_expiry_days*(60*60*12);
        $toold=date('Y-m-d',$temp);
    }
    else $toold=0;
    $search_mod=0;

    $query->select(
        $this->getState(
            'list.select',
            'a.id, a.categories_id, a.number, a.headline, a.short_description, a.lat, a.lon, a.published, a.dpublished' .
            ', a.featured, a.address_name, a.created, a.modified, p.name , a.price_night, a.price_week, a.sleeps'
        )
    );

    $query->from('#__jomholiday_listings AS a');

    $query->select('p.name AS image');
    $query->select('MAX(p.id)');
    $query->join('LEFT', '#__jomholiday_photos AS p ON p.listings_id = a.id AND (p.rooms_id=0 OR p.rooms_id IS NULL)  ');

    $query->select('ac.name AS category_name');
    $query->select('ac.rental AS price_type');
    $query->join('LEFT', '#__jomholiday_categories AS ac ON ac.id = a.categories_id');
    $query->where("(ac.lang='".$lang->getTag()."' OR ac.lang='*')");
    //$query->where("p.id = MAX(p.id)");
    $query->select('AVG(r.rating) AS rating_average');
    $query->join('LEFT', '#__jomholiday_reviews AS r ON r.published="1" AND r.listingid=a.id');

    if ($rating_id){    
        $query->select('f1.value AS accomodation_rating');
        $query->join('LEFT', '#__jomholiday_listings_to_fields AS f1 ON f1.listings_id = a.id AND f1.fields_id='.$rating_id.'');
    }
    if ($board_basis_id){   
        $query->select('f2.value AS all_inclusive');
        $query->join('LEFT', '#__jomholiday_listings_to_fields AS f2 ON f2.listings_id = a.id AND f2.fields_id='.$board_basis_id.' and f2.value="COM_JOMHOLIDAY_ALL_INCLUSIVE"');

        $query->select('f3.value AS bed_breakfast');
        $query->join('LEFT', '#__jomholiday_listings_to_fields AS f3 ON f3.listings_id = a.id AND f3.fields_id='.$board_basis_id.' and f3.value="COM_JOMHOLIDAY_BED_BREAKFAST"');

        $query->select('f4.value AS full_board');
        $query->join('LEFT', '#__jomholiday_listings_to_fields AS f4 ON f4.listings_id = a.id AND f4.fields_id='.$board_basis_id.' and f4.value="COM_JOMHOLIDAY_FULL_BOARD"');

        $query->select('f5.value AS half_board');
        $query->join('LEFT', '#__jomholiday_listings_to_fields AS f5 ON f5.listings_id = a.id AND f5.fields_id='.$board_basis_id.' and f5.value="COM_JOMHOLIDAY_HALF_BOARD"');

        $query->select('f6.value AS room_only');
        $query->join('LEFT', '#__jomholiday_listings_to_fields AS f6 ON f6.listings_id = a.id AND f6.fields_id='.$board_basis_id.' and f6.value="COM_JOMHOLIDAY_ROOM_ONLY"');

        $query->select('f7.value AS self_cattering');
        $query->join('LEFT', '#__jomholiday_listings_to_fields AS f7 ON f7.listings_id = a.id AND f7.fields_id='.$board_basis_id.' and f7.value="COM_JOMHOLIDAY_SELF_CATTERING"');

    }
    if ($saved)
    {
        $cids=JRequest::getString('savedlist', '', 'cookie');
        $cid=explode(",",$cids);
        JArrayHelper::toInteger($cid);
        $cids=implode(",",$cid);
        $query->where('a.id IN ( '. $cids .' )');
        $search_mod=1;
    }

    $query->where("a.published='1'");
    $query->where("a.approved='1'");
    if ($toold) $query->where("a.dpublished>'$toold'");

    if ($session->get('jom_zlat')!=null)
    {
        $lat1=(float)$session->get('jom_lat')-$session->get('jom_zlat');
        $lat2=(float)$session->get('jom_lat')+$session->get('jom_zlat');
        $lon1=(float)$session->get('jom_lon')-$session->get('jom_zlon');
        $lon2=(float)$session->get('jom_lon')+$session->get('jom_zlon');
        if ($lat1>$lat2){$temp=$lat1;$lat1=$lat2;$lat2=$temp;}
        if ($lon1>$lon2){$temp=$lon1;$lat1=$lon2;$lon2=$temp;}
        if ($lat1) $query->where("a.lat>".$lat1);
        if ($lat2) $query->where("a.lat<".$lat2);
        if ($lon1) $query->where("a.lon>".$lon1);
        if ($lon2) $query->where("a.lon<".$lon2);
        $search_mod=1;
    }
    if ($session->get('jom_address_select')!=null)
    {
        $temp=explode(",",$session->get('jom_address_select'));
        if ($temp[0]) $temp1=$this->getRegion((int)$temp[0]);
        if ($temp[1]) $temp1.=", ".$this->getRegion((int)$temp[1]);
        if ($temp[2]) $temp1.=", ".$this->getRegion((int)$temp[2]);
        $query->where("(a.address_name like '%".str_replace("'","\'",$temp1)."%')", ENT_QUOTES);
        $search_mod=1;
    }
    if (str_replace(",","",$session->get('jom_booking')))
    {
        $temp=explode(",",$session->get('jom_booking'));
        if ($temp[0] && $temp[2]>0)
        {
            $in=strtotime($temp[0]);
            $out=strtotime($temp[1]);
            $query->where("a.sleeps >= '".(int)$temp[2]."'");
            while ($in<$out)
            {
                $query->where("(a.booking LIKE '%,".date("ymd",$in)."-".(int)$temp[2].",%' OR a.booking NOT LIKE '%,".date("ymd",$in)."-%' OR a.booking IS NULL)");
                $in=strtotime('+1 day', $in);
            }
        }
        $search_mod=1;
    }
    if ((int)$session->get('jomholiday_search_cat'))
    {
        $temp=explode(",",$session->get('jomholiday_search_cat'));
        JArrayHelper::toInteger($temp);
        $cidss = implode( ',', $temp );
        $query->where("a.categories_id IN ( ". $cidss ." )");
        $search_mod=1;
    }
    if ($session->get('jom_title')!=null){$search_mod=1; $query->where("(a.headline like '%".str_replace("'","\'",$session->get('jom_title'))."%' OR a.address_name like '%".str_replace("'","\'",$session->get('jom_title'))."%')", ENT_QUOTES);}
    if ((int)$session->get('jom_pricemin')!=null){$search_mod=1; $query->where("a.price_night>=".(int)$session->get('jom_pricemin'));}
    if ((int)$session->get('jom_pricemax')!=null) {$search_mod=1;$query->where("a.price_night<=".(int)$session->get('jom_pricemax'));}

    if ($session->get('jomholiday_search'))
    {
        $val=json_decode($session->get('jomholiday_search'),true);
        if (is_array($val))
        {
            $array_keys = array_keys($val);
            foreach($array_keys as $key) if ($val[$key]!=null)
            {
                    if (is_array($val[$key]))
                    {
                        $array_keys1 = array_keys($val[$key]);
                        foreach($array_keys1 as $key1)
                        {
                            $val[$key][$key1]=htmlspecialchars($val[$key][$key1],ENT_QUOTES);
                            $query->where('exists(select 1 from #__jomholiday_listings_to_fields AS fs'.$key.'_'.$key1.' where fs'.$key.'_'.$key1.'.listings_id = a.id AND fs'.$key.'_'.$key1.'.value="'.$val[$key][$key1].'" and fs'.$key.'_'.$key1.'.fields_id='.$key.')');
                        }
                    }
                    else if (trim($val[$key])!=null)
                    {
                        $val[$key]=htmlspecialchars(trim($val[$key]),ENT_QUOTES);
                        $query->where('exists(select 1 from #__jomholiday_listings_to_fields AS fs'.$key.' where fs'.$key.'.listings_id = a.id AND fs'.$key.'.value="'.$val[$key].'" and fs'.$key.'.fields_id='.$key.')');
                    }
            }
            $search_mod=1;
        }
    }

    if ((int)JRequest::getVar('cid') && !$search_mod) $query->where("a.categories_id='".(int)JRequest::getVar('cid')."'");

    if ((int)$session->get('jom_pricemin_f')!=null) $query->where("a.price_night>=".(int)$session->get('jom_pricemin_f'));
    if ((int)$session->get('jom_pricemax_f')!=null) $query->where("a.price_night<=".(int)$session->get('jom_pricemax_f'));

    if ($session->get('jomholiday_filter'))
    {
        $val=json_decode($session->get('jomholiday_filter'),true);
        if (is_array($val))
        {
            $array_keys = array_keys($val);
            foreach($array_keys as $key) if ($val[$key]!=null)
            {
                    if (is_array($val[$key]))
                    {
                        $array_keys1 = array_keys($val[$key]);
                        foreach($array_keys1 as $key1)
                        {
                            $val[$key][$key1]=htmlspecialchars($val[$key][$key1],ENT_QUOTES);
                            $query->where('exists(select 1 from #__jomholiday_listings_to_fields AS fsf'.$key.'_'.$key1.' where fsf'.$key.'_'.$key1.'.listings_id = a.id AND fsf'.$key.'_'.$key1.'.value="'.$val[$key][$key1].'" and fsf'.$key.'_'.$key1.'.fields_id='.$key.')');
                        }
                    }
                    else if (trim($val[$key])!=null)
                    {
                        $val[$key]=htmlspecialchars(trim($val[$key]),ENT_QUOTES);
                        $query->where('exists(select 1 from #__jomholiday_listings_to_fields AS fsf'.$key.' where fsf'.$key.'.listings_id = a.id AND fsf'.$key.'.value="'.$val[$key].'" and fsf'.$key.'.fields_id='.$key.')');
                    }
            }
        }
    }
    if ($session->get('jom_address')!=null) $query->where("a.address_name like '".str_replace("'","\'",$session->get('jom_address'))."%'", ENT_QUOTES);

    $query->group("a.id");
    if ($this->getState('sort_by')=="a.created DESC") $order_s=$this->getState('sort_by');
    elseif ($this->getState('sort_by')=="a.modified DESC") $order_s=$this->getState('sort_by');
    elseif ($this->getState('sort_by')=="a.price_night DESC") $order_s=$this->getState('sort_by');
    elseif ($this->getState('sort_by')=="a.price_night") $order_s=$this->getState('sort_by');
    elseif ($this->getState('sort_by')=="a.headline") $order_s=$this->getState('sort_by');
    else $order_s="";
    if ($this->getConf(premium_first))
    {
        if ($order_s && JRequest::getVar('task')!='rss') $query->order("a.featured desc, ".$order_s.",id desc");
        else $query->order("a.featured desc, a.created DESC, id desc");
    }
    else
    {

        if ($order_s && JRequest::getVar('task')!='rss') $query->order($order_s.",id desc");
        else $query->order("a.created DESC, id desc");
    }

    if ($saved || JRequest::getVar('task')=='rss') $data = $this->_getList($query);
    else $data = $this->_getList($query, $this->getState('limitstart'), $this->getState('limit'));
    //echo $query;
    return $data;   
}
```

I need to retrive last inserted image from table #__jomholiday_photos. As you can see I did try to put the MAX(p.id) but that didn't helped. 
I did try to put the $query->order("p.id DESC"); , that didn't helped aether.

Update: 
Here is a query that is generated with this code

```
SELECT a.id, a.categories_id, a.number, a.headline, a.short_description, a.lat, a.lon,
 a.published, a.dpublished, a.featured, a.address_name, a.created, a.modified,
 p.name , a.price_night, a.price_week, a.sleeps,p.name AS image,MAX(p.id),ac.name AS category_name,
 ac.rental AS price_type,AVG(r.rating) AS rating_average,f1.value AS accomodation_rating,
 f2.value AS all_inclusive,f3.value AS bed_breakfast,f4.value AS full_board,f5.value AS half_board,
 f6.value AS room_only,f7.value AS self_cattering 
 FROM #__jomholiday_listings AS a 
 LEFT JOIN #__jomholiday_photos AS p ON p.listings_id = a.id AND (p.rooms_id=0 OR p.rooms_id IS NULL)  
 LEFT JOIN #__jomholiday_categories AS ac ON ac.id = a.categories_id 
  LEFT JOIN #__jomholiday_reviews AS r ON r.published="1" AND r.listingid=a.id 
  LEFT JOIN #__jomholiday_listings_to_fields AS f1 ON f1.listings_id = a.id 
  AND f1.fields_id=22
  LEFT JOIN #__jomholiday_listings_to_fields AS f2 ON f2.listings_id = a.id 
  AND f2.fields_id=10 
  and f2.value="COM_JOMHOLIDAY_ALL_INCLUSIVE" LEFT JOIN #__jomholiday_listings_to_fields AS f3 
  ON f3.listings_id = a.id AND f3.fields_id=10 and f3.value="COM_JOMHOLIDAY_BED_BREAKFAST" 
  LEFT JOIN #__jomholiday_listings_to_fields AS f4 ON f4.listings_id = a.id 
  AND f4.fields_id=10 
  and f4.value="COM_JOMHOLIDAY_FULL_BOARD" LEFT JOIN #__jomholiday_listings_to_fields AS f5 
  ON f5.listings_id = a.id AND f5.fields_id=10 and f5.value="COM_JOMHOLIDAY_HALF_BOARD" 
  LEFT JOIN #__jomholiday_listings_to_fields AS f6 ON f6.listings_id = a.id 
   AND f6.fields_id=10 
  and f6.value="COM_JOMHOLIDAY_ROOM_ONLY" LEFT JOIN #__jomholiday_listings_to_fields AS f7 
  ON f7.listings_id = a.id AND f7.fields_id=10 and f7.value="COM_JOMHOLIDAY_SELF_CATTERING" 
  WHERE (ac.lang='hr-HR' OR ac.lang='*') 
  AND a.published='1' AND a.approved='1' 
    GROUP BY a.id 
   ORDER BY a.featured desc,    a.headline,id desc LIMIT 0, 15
```

'p.name' retrieves the firs record from '#__jomholiday_photos'. I need the last one of each listings.

Comment: That's really hard to read and you should switch to using the API if possible.   Do each of the generated queries work when you run them directly in phpmyadmin or whereever?

Comment: Yes, everything works like it is, but  #__jomholiday_photos has more than one image, and I need to retrieve the last inserted not the first.

Comment: No I can't really see beause it's about 80 lines of uncommented code and I don't even know where to begin to look for the code you are referring to. I'd really encourage you always to use curly brackets around conditionals even if they are only one line, it's a goto fail waiting to happen otherwise.  If I were you I would $query->dump() the and test in phpmyadmin.

Comment: Also if you are going to keep reusing the same variable name for your queries you need to $query->clear() in between.

Comment: I'm sorry for the bad code. This is from a plug-in jomholiday joomla. They didn't programmed the functionality to select the main image for the every single accommodation. So I thought to modify the code so that every last image uploaded is the main image. All I need is to retrieve the the image with MAX(id)

Comment: Ok so here is your order by `ORDER BY a.featured desc,    a.headline,id desc LIMIT 0, 15`    which is not going to give you the id as the main sort.  Try running it in phpmyadmin with  just id for the sort.

Answer (score 0):

I founded how to get the last image by replacing this code:

```
 $query->join('LEFT', '#__jomholiday_photos AS p ON p.listings_id = a.id AND (p.rooms_id=0 OR p.rooms_id IS NULL)   ');
```

with this one:

```
$query->join('LEFT', '( SELECT MAX(id) as maxpid , name, listings_id, rooms_id FROM #__jomholiday_photos GROUP BY id ORDER BY id DESC) AS p ON p.listings_id = a.id AND (p.rooms_id=0 OR p.rooms_id IS NULL)   ');
```